# Discord.py Rewrite custom errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

i am very new to coding and i was wondering how would i implement custom errors like "missing a dev role" in here:

```
    @bot.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Temp.", "Owner")
async def sh(ctx):
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(':true:508022488093949973')
    await ctx.send("<a:siren:507952050181636098> `Shutting down` <a:siren:507952050181636098>")
    await bot.logout()
```

I have a simple handler like this

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(':false:508021839981707304')
    await ctx.send("<a:siren:507952050181636098> `Invalid command` <a:siren:507952050181636098>")
```

but it always just ouputs invalid command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the class of `error` to determine what kind of error you are handling.  If you pair this with a command-specific [error handler](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling), you can write a response that tells the user what they are missing:

```
@sh.error
async def sh_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        await ctx.send("You do not have the correct roles Temp. or Owner")

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if not isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure): 
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(':false:508021839981707304')
        await ctx.send("<a:siren:507952050181636098> `Invalid command` <a:siren:507952050181636098>")
```